# SQL: nested select statement - child select reading var from main select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have 3 tables called `OrderTbl`, `OrderDetailTbl`, and `ProductTbl`.

**OrderTbl** columns include these:

```
OrderId | EventDate | etc...
```

**OrderDetailTbl** columns include these:

```
ProductId(fk) | RequiredQuantity | OrderId(fk) | etc...
```

**ProductTbl** columns include these:

```
ProductId | ProductName | TotalQuantityInStock
```

My goal is to create a stored procedure that will be called by my application to view data inside datatable that will combine data from the three tables that look like this

```
ProductName | Total Quantity | EventDate | TotalRequiredQuantity
Product1    |  100           |  1-1-2019 | 20
Product2    |  200           |  1-1-2019 | 55
Product1    |  100           |  2-1-2019 | 60
```

I created a statement as follows:-

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temptbl', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    /*Then it exists*/
    DROP TABLE #temptbl

SELECT DISTINCT
    p.ProductName, p.TotalQuantity, o.OrderEventDate, 
    (SELECT SUM(od.OrderDetailReqQuant)
     FROM OrderDetailTbl AS od
     INNER JOIN OrderTbl AS o ON od.OrderId = o.OrderId
     WHERE o.OrderEventDate = '2019-01-18' 
       AND od.ProductId = 1002) AS TotalRequiredQuantity
INTO
    #temptbl
FROM
    ProductTbl AS p
INNER JOIN
    OrderDetailTbl AS od ON p.ProductID = od.ProductId
INNER JOIN
    OrderTbl AS o ON o.OrderId = od.OrderId

SELECT * FROM #temptbl
```

The statement produces the following results:

```
ProductName    | TotalQuantity | OrderEventDate | TotalRequiredQuantity
---------------+---------------+----------------+----------------------
8' Tabel       |       50      | 2019-01-18     |     12
Banquet Chairs |      400      | 2019-01-17     |     12
Banquet Chairs |      400      | 2019-01-18     |     12
White Chairs   |      220      | 2019-01-18     |     12
```

All the data is correct except for the `TotalRequiredQuantity` column, as you can see the data passed to the statement is static my question is the following:

how to pass the current  p.ProductName and o.OrderEventDate which is in the main select statement to the child select statement? I know for the  od.ProductId I have to run another select statement which will fetch the the productId that is corresponding to p.ProductName, but that will not be a problem for me.

Thanks peeps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after playing around with the statement, that was the final result that worked for me:-

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temptbl', 'U') IS NOT NULL
/*Then it exists*/
DROP TABLE #temptbl

declare @totalreq int

select distinct p1.ProductName, p1.TotalQuantity, o1.OrderEventDate, (select SUM(od2.OrderDetailReqQuant)
                from OrderDetailTbl as od2
                inner join OrderTbl as o2
                    on od2.OrderId = o2.OrderId
                where o2.OrderEventDate = o1.OrderEventDate and od2.ProductId = 

                (select p3.ProductId from ProductTbl as p3 where p3.ProductName = p1.ProductName))  as TotalRequiredQuantity
into #temptbl
 from ProductTbl as p1
 inner join OrderDetailTbl as od1
    on p1.ProductID = od1.ProductId
 inner join OrderTbl as o1
    on o1.OrderId = od1.OrderId

    select * from #temptbl
```

all what I did is on each level of select statement I defined a unique name of reused table, so lets say in the main select statement I defined producttbl as p1 and in the first subquery I defined the producttbl again as p2 and in the second subquery I defined the producttbl as p3, so now I can compare values coming from the 3 levels of the statement and display result correctly. the results were as follows:-

```
ProductName    |TotalQuantity|OrderEventDate|TotalRequiredQuantity
__________________________________________________________________________
8' Tabel       | 50          | 2019-01-18   |14
Banquet Chairs |400          | 2019-01-17   |2
Banquet Chairs |400          | 2019-01-18   |12
White Chairs   |220          | 2019-01-18   |5
```

Comment: I don't think that your query is written well, check my third suggestion in my answer

Comment: Also from your answer it looks like your question was not clear!!

Answer (score 1):

*I am not very sure what you a re trying to do with the `o.OrderEventDate = '2019-01-18' and od.ProductId = 1002` filter, so i will give 3 suggestions:*

First of all, you must remove the inner join from the subquery.

**First suggestion (keep the filter inside the sub-query)**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.ProductName, p.TotalQuantity, o.OrderEventDate, (select SUM(od.OrderDetailReqQuant)
        FROM OrderDetailTbl as od
        WHERE od.OrderId = o.OrderId and o.OrderEventDate = '2019-01-18' and od.ProductId = 1002)  as TotalRequiredQuantity
INTO #temptbl
FROM ProductTbl as p
INNER JOIN OrderDetailTbl as od ON p.ProductID = od.ProductId
INNER JOIN OrderTbl as o ON o.OrderId = od.OrderId
```

**Second suggestion (move the filter to the original query)**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.ProductName, p.TotalQuantity, o.OrderEventDate, (select SUM(od.OrderDetailReqQuant)
        FROM OrderDetailTbl as od
        WHERE od.OrderId = o.OrderId)  as TotalRequiredQuantity
INTO #temptbl
FROM ProductTbl as p
INNER JOIN OrderDetailTbl as od ON p.ProductID = od.ProductId
INNER JOIN OrderTbl as o ON o.OrderId = od.OrderId
WHERE o.OrderEventDate = '2019-01-18' and od.ProductId = 1002
```

**Third suggestion (remove the filter)**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.ProductName, p.TotalQuantity, o.OrderEventDate, (select SUM(od.OrderDetailReqQuant)
        FROM OrderDetailTbl as od
        WHERE od.OrderId = o.OrderId and p.ProductId = od.ProductId)  as TotalRequiredQuantity
INTO #temptbl
FROM ProductTbl as p
INNER JOIN OrderDetailTbl as od ON p.ProductID = od.ProductId
INNER JOIN OrderTbl as o ON o.OrderId = od.OrderId
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this internal made column via

```
       (select SUM(od.OrderDetailReqQuant)
        from OrderDetailTbl as od
        inner join OrderTbl as o
            on od.OrderId = o.OrderId
                  where o.OrderEventDate = '2019-01-18' and 
              od.ProductId = 1002)....
```

and just add this additional condition `o.OrderEventDate = '2019-01-18' and od.ProductId = 1002` in the where clause itself